# If multiple items from list in other list - Python

Tags: python

I want to see if multiple items from one list are in another.

So this part of the program is basically:

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d]
list2 = [c, d, e, f]
if 2(list1) in list2
#Do Stuff
```

But this returns the error:
"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: ``2(list1)`` doesn't mean anything in python, are you trying to check for the existence of at least two elements from list1 in list2?

Comment: @Jesse Yes, sorry forgot to add what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [sets intersection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) to find how many common elements in two lists:

```
if len(set(list1) & set(list2)) >= 2:
```

Comment: Thank You, this seems too be working perfectly!

Comment: `>= 2` for "multiple items"

Comment: Creating `set(list2)` is unnecessary, you can also do `set(list1).intersection(list2)` to construct one less set.

Comment: @wim just tested both variants with timeit: set() & set() consumes a little less time - timeit('set(l1).intersection(l2)', setup='l1=[1,2,3]*1000; l2=[3,4,5]*1000', number=100000) and timeit('len(set(l1) & set(l2))', setup='l1=[1,2,3]*1000; l2=[3,4,5]*1000', number=100000)

Comment: surprise, I wonder why that's the case ..

Answer (score 2):

if you convert your lists to sets you can find the elements that are in both by using setintersection

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f']

common = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

You can then test the length of the result list to do your stuff

```
if(common):
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to check if a subset of 2 items from the first list is contained in the second list. This can be done as:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
if len(set(list1).intersection(set(list2))) == 2:
    #Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are trying to call `2` as a function. It just ins't syntactically or semantically correct.

To see if multiple items from one list are in another do this:

```
count = 0
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        count += 1

if count == 2:
    # do stuff
```

The for-loop iterates through list one and counts how many items in list1 are in list2. Then, once that's done you can check the counter for the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see which items exist in both lists it is easier with sets :

```
print set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do is some simple set arithmetic:

```
if len(set(list1) & set(list2)) == 2:
    # code to execute conditionally
```

This will convert each of your lists to sets, which are a similar data structure to lists but operate with the same constraints as mathematical sets.  For more information I would check out the [Python docs on sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)